# Delete unpublished app from devices who have it installed (Android)

Tags: android, mobile

We unpublished an Android-app from the Google play-store. We still see that it is installed on 500+ devices. Is there a way to remove it from these devices? If not, is there a way to show people who open the app a message?

If for both questions the answer is no, what would be the way to go?

Br.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, the answer would be no for the first aspect of the question and a maybe no for the second aspect of the question. The thing is that if you have some kind of connectivity in your app, i.e. some type of way to communicate with your users built by you, then you could use that channel to communicate whatever you desire. If not, well then you can't force them to uninstall the app. They got the app when it was available, and you've got no control over what apps a person has on their phone, even if you made that app.

Best of luck.